# What is the proper way to migrate this pom maven task to maven-publish?

Tags: java, maven, gradle, artifacts, maven-publish

I have this task in my build.gradle file that was using maven:

```
task pom {
    doLast {
        pom {
            project {
                groupId "${project.group}.${project.name}"
                artifactId project.name
                version project.version
            }
        }.writeTo ("$buildDir/libs/${project.name}.pom")
    }
}
```

Now its my task to get this project ready for gradle 7, and part of that means upgrading maven to maven-publish. The above code snippit doesn't work with maven-publish, as pom() isn't a recognized method. What is the proper way to migrate this code over to maven-publish?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have questions about the [maven-publish documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html)?

Comment: @Jeremy I've taken a look at the documentation but am mostly not sure how to point it to a location to write the POM to (like .writeTo in this situation).

Answer (score 1):

Try this, based on the [Official Gradle Publishing Maven page](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/publishing_maven.html#publishing_maven:tasks):

```
publishing {
    publications {
        MavenCustom(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            groupId "${project.group}.${project.name}"
            artifactId project.name
            version project.version
        }
    }
}

model {
    tasks.generatePomFileForMavenCustomPublication {
        destination = file("$buildDir/libs/${project.name}.pom.xml")
    }
}
```